# How to put a route in an IconButton widget [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter

I want my Icons.arrow_back to be a custom one for me, one that I have in SVG, but I have the path, I don't know how to place it correctly.

```
leading: new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back, 
                color: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary,
                size: 40.0,
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
```

Comment: I use [this icon generator](https://www.fluttericon.com/) for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers from the Flutter community created a lib to handle svg files. We can use it as  Or you can use **Image.assets** also for this and then wrape on **Gesture Detector** ontap(){ /** **call the navigator.pop** **/ }
or you may use **Flutter SVG plugin** also

```
 leading :  new SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/candle.svg',
      height: 20.0,
      width: 20.0,
      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
    ),
```

I found a small example of SVG https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/06/flutter-draw-svg-vector-drawables.html